# Using printf in C when I don't know how many arguments until runtime

Tags: c, variables, runtime, arguments, printf

I have a situation where I am trying to print out information that is formatted by the user in Lua and sent to me through a registered function.  What I get from the customer is a format string, the number of arguments, and each argument as a number.  I don't know how many arguments the user will have until this function is called.  I get them by querying the lua system.

How do I call printf with the format string and the list of numbers during runtime?  I can allocate an array at runtime for the values of the numbers, but printf is expecting an va_list not a number array for the parameters.

I could have a ton of 'if' statements based upon the number of arguments, but I was looking for a slicker way.

Any ideas?

Comment: loop through the list in your function and append to the previous printf?.

Comment: Try vprintf. IIRC it works with arrays

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to print out the values you could use a for loop to loop through all the values and print them individually, just **without** a newline.

Comment: As printf bufferises, you wont suffer of any performance lack.

Comment: That would normally work but in this case the user is going to want to format each number differently (6 decimal places for the 1st number, no decimal places for the next, etc.)

Comment: Why would that be a problem, if you know that beforehand...?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use one printf that prints %s, and as argument you pass your function that will return char*. The function would accept array of the parameters as argument. Inside function you can format all parameters to "string" using sprintf and at end return created "string".

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling the printf repeatedly inside a loop, which obviously runs "number of arguments" times would work. I mean to say something like:

```
void YourFunction(char *format, int number_of_arguments, int *arguments)
{
    for(int index = 0; index < number_of_arguments; index++)
    {
        printf(format, arguments[index]);
    }
}
```

Now you can format it the way you want, like add newline characters by doing,

```
strcat(format, "\n");
```

Correct me if I misunderstood your question.